# Do I'm missing something in code? The results are not right

Tags: c, character

I'm new to programming, trying to learn C.
The program below is showing no signs of error still the output is not correct. I tried it without using '&' sign as "ms" and "sc" are characters but still that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post text *as* text. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `scanf("%c,&ms")` --> `scanf(" %c", &ms);`; same for `&sc`. The arguments should not be *inside* the string. Please turn up your compiler warnings (`gcc -Wall ...`).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you missed enclosing quotation marks in the scanf call

replace the following

```
line 5: scanf("%c",&ms)

line 7: scanf("%c",&sc)
```